# Conversion to datetime object leads to crash of numpy functions

Tags: python, numpy

My python script produces an strange error and I have no clue why. Maybe anybody else has an idea. 
Try to provide a example everybody else should be able to run.

```
import datetime 
import numpy as np

date = np.array([20120203123054, 20120204123054]) #date format: YYYYMMDDhhmmss
longitude = np.array([52., 53.])
latitude = np.array([-22.0, -23.0])

# Loop to convert date into datetime object 
date_new = []
for j in range(len(date)):  
    date_string = str(date[j])
    dt=datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string[:],'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    date_new.append(dt) 

data = np.array([date, longitude, latitude]) 
data_new = np.array([date_new, longitude, latitude]) 

#function to calculate distance between two locations (fixed location: 
#longitude=50.,latitude=-20.)
def calculate_distance(longi, lati):
    distance = []
    latitude = ((50. + lati)/2)* 0.01745
    dx = 111.3 * np.cos(latitude) * (50. - longi)
    dy = 111.3 * (-20. - lati)
    d = np.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
    distance.append(d)  
    return distance

#call function
calculate_distance(data[1], data[2]) # Script works!
calculate_distance(data_new[1], data_new[2]) # Script doesn't work!  
                                             # see Traceback below
```

Why does it crash?

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "data_analysis.py" line 85,
dx = 111.3 * cos(latitude) * (lon_station - longitude)
AttributeError: cos
```

Comment: Please provide [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: In the absence of an SSCCE, this is only a guess, but probably your array has `dtype=object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy` arrays don't play so well with heterogeneous types.  When you made `data_new`, you were storing different kinds of Python objects in it, and so that forced the `dtype` to be `object` to be broad enough to handle everything.

```
>>> data
array([[  2.01202031e+13,   2.01202041e+13],
       [  5.20000000e+01,   5.30000000e+01],
       [ -2.20000000e+01,  -2.30000000e+01]])
>>> data.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> data_new
array([[datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 3, 12, 30, 54),
        datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 4, 12, 30, 54)],
       [52.0, 53.0],
       [-22.0, -23.0]], dtype=object)
>>> data_new.dtype
dtype('O')
```

Since taking the cosine of an arbitrary object doesn't make sense, this isn't implemented:

```
>>> np.cos(data[1])
array([-0.16299078, -0.91828279])
>>> np.cos(data_new[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-87-00101e4be00a>", line 1, in <module>
    np.cos(data_new[1])
AttributeError: cos
```

You can return to `float` type (unfortunately it doesn't look like you can use a `view` with object arrays):

```
>>> np.cos(data_new[1].astype(float))
array([-0.16299078, -0.91828279])
```

FWIW I prefer [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) DataFrames when working with this kind of mixed-type data, but people's preferences vary.  I don't know enough about numpy structured arrays to know if you can mix object dtypes and more primitive dtypes, although I didn't think so.